# When is the earliest you can apply for a visa in connection with the UK Youth Mobility Scheme?

Tags: visas, uk

I'm a bit confused by this statement in the information about applying for the Youth Mobility Scheme:

> The earliest you can apply for a visa is 6 months before you travel.

Lets say I applied in February 2017 and wanted to go to the UK in April. Is that possible? Do I have to wait 6 months, until August, before I enter UK and put that as my starting date? Can my starting date can be any time within the 6 months from my application date?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can apply now for a visa to start in April: your starting date must be within six months from your application date.

What you can't do is to apply *more* than six months before you travel.

As an example, you couldn't have applied in September 2016 for a visa starting in April 2017.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what I mean is apply now and I want to activate my visa on April not just visit.

Comment: @Jomar I don't understand what you mean by "activating a visa".

Comment: @Jomar: "Activating a visa" isn't recognised by the authorities. I assume you want to apply for a visa now and not take it up, but say some time next year "Here's the proof that I am entitled to a visa, can you issue it now please?" If so, this cannot possibly work; too many things might have changed between now and then (which is presumably the reason for the rule in the first place).

Comment: I think OP was confused by the original wording "to visit in April." I've modified the answer a little to hopefully make it clearer to the OP.

Comment: Lets say I apply on Feb 2017 for youth mobility scheme can my intend date to enter UK as youth mobility scheme holder be March 2017?

Comment: @Jomar Yes, because you're applying one month before you want to visit, which is less than six months.

Comment: alright so my intend date must be within 6 months on the date of my application?

Comment: @Jomar Correct.

Comment: @Jomar you can show your appreciation by accepting DavidRicharby's answer by activating the tick mark.

Comment: @Jomar please be courteous to David and accept his answer.  You can read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for why this is important.  Thanks